# Update more than one inner document in MongoDb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

In my example project, I have employees under manager. Db schema is like this;

```
{
  "employees": [
    {
      "name": "Adam",
      "_id": "5ea36b27d7ae560845afb88e",
      "bananas": "allowed"
    },
    {
      "name": "Smith",
      "_id": "5ea36b27d7ae560845afb88f",
      "bananas": "not-allowed"
    },
    {
      "name": "John",
      "_id": "5ea36b27d7ae560845afb88g",
      "bananas": "not-allowed"
    },
    {
      "name": "Patrick",
      "_id": "5ea36b27d7ae560845afb88h",
      "bananas": "allowed"
    }
  ]
}
```

In this case **Adam** is allowed to eat bananas and **Smith** is not. If I have to give the permission of eating bananas from **Adam** to **Smith** I need to perform update operation twice like this:

```
db.managers.update(
    { 'employees.name': 'Adam' },
    { $set: { 'employees.$.bananas': 'not-allowed' } }
);
```

and

```
db.managers.update(
    { 'employees.name': 'Smith' },
    { $set: { 'employees.$.bananas': 'allowed' } }
);
```

Is it possible to handle this in a single query?

Comment: Thanks @ElieAsmar, I found the answer useful and solved the current issue but it's not a scalable one. That's why I gave an up point but didn't mark the answer. This has limitations, if I have to update Adam and Patrick allowed, Smith and John not-allowed (Or imagine Adam is updated as having 15 bananas, Smith has 12 bananas and John is updated as having 17 bananas).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$map` and `$cond` to perform conditional update to the array entries depending on the name of the employee. A `$switch` is used for potential extension of cases.

```js
db.collection.update({},
[
  {
    "$set": {
      "employees": {
        "$map": {
          "input": "$employees",
          "as": "e",
          "in": {
            "$switch": {
              "branches": [
                {
                  "case": {
                    $eq: [
                      "$$e.name",
                      "Adam"
                    ]
                  },
                  "then": {
                    "$mergeObjects": [
                      "$$e",
                      {
                        "bananas": "not-allowed"
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                },
                {
                  "case": {
                    $eq: [
                      "$$e.name",
                      "Smith"
                    ]
                  },
                  "then": {
                    "$mergeObjects": [
                      "$$e",
                      {
                        "bananas": "allowed"
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                }
              ],
              default: "$$e"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/GUNHLfvyFN4)

Answer (score 1):

```
db.managers.update(
   {
      $or: [
         {"employees.name": "Adam"},
         {"employees.name": "Smith"}
      ]
   },
   {
      $set: {
         "employees.$[e].bananas": {
            $cond: [{ $eq: ["$e.name", "Adam"] }, "not-allowed", "allowed"]
         }
      }
   },
   {
      arrayFilters: [{ "e.name": { $in: ["Adam", "Smith"] } }]
   }
)
```